# Inserting records into mysql using java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
package Simple;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;


public class CheckJdbc {

  private static final String DB_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
  private static final String DB_CONNECTION = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db";

  private static final String DB_USER = "root";
  private static final String DB_PASSWORD = "root";

  private static int RECORD_COUNT = 1;
  static final String DATEFORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
  static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd";
  static final String TIME_FORMAT = "HH:mm:ss";
  private static final int ADD_MINUTES = 2;
  static final String FromDate = "2016-01-01 00:00:00";

  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    List<String> records = new ArrayList<String>();
    StringBuffer record = new StringBuffer();
    DateFormat d_f = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    DateFormat tf = new SimpleDateFormat(TIME_FORMAT);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(d_f.parse(FromDate));
   // record.append("\t");
    for (int i = 1; i <= RECORD_COUNT; i++) {
        records = new ArrayList<String>(RECORD_COUNT);
      }
      for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {

          int a2 = 230 + j % 15; // 230 - 244 by 1
          String wString = Integer.toString(a2);
          String a = String.valueOf(a2);
          record.append(a+" ");            
          double b2 = 1.3 + j % 17 ; // 1.3 - 2.9 by 0.1 
          String aString = Double.toString(b2);
          String b = String.valueOf(b2);
          record.append(b+" ");  
          double c2 = 0.01 + j % 49 * 0.01; // 0.01 - 0.49 by 0.01
          String bString = Double.toString(c2);
          String c = String.valueOf(c2);
          record.append(c+" ");         

      record.append((d_f.format(cal.getTime()))+" "+tf.format(cal.getTime())+" ");

        record.delete(0, record.length());
        record.append(a + "," + b + "," + c );
        record.append("\t\t");

        record.append("\n");
        cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, ADD_MINUTES);
        records.add(record.toString());

    try {
        String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO cmd"
                + "(a, b, c) " + "VALUES"
                + "("+record.toString()+")";
            System.out.println("insertTableSQL - " + insertTableSQL);     
            Statement.executeUpdate(insertTableSQL);

      insertRecordIntodb();
      Connection dbConnection = null;
      Statement statement = null;
      dbConnection = getDBConnection();
      statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
      System.out.println(insertTableSQL);
      // execute insert SQL stetement
      statement.executeUpdate(insertTableSQL);
      System.out.println(insertTableSQL);
      System.out.println("Record is inserted into Db table!");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
    }
  }
    }

  private static void insertRecordIntodb() {

  }

  private static Connection getDBConnection() {
    Connection dbConnection = null;
    try {
      Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    try {
      dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_CONNECTION, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
      return dbConnection;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return dbConnection;
  }
}
```

I am trying to insert data into mysql db i am getting some of values but there is exception saying that :Field 'd_f' doesn't have a default value.Getting following output in stack trace:->

```
INSERT INTO cmd(a, b, c) VALUES(233,4.3,0.040)
    Field 'd_f' doesn't have a default value
```

Is My Insert statement wrong or format?

Comment: is d_f column non nullable, in table you are trying to insert record into?

Comment: yes i have taken d_f as a date

Comment: if you want that field to be optional while doing an insert, then set is as nullable in your table or provide a default value

Comment: The error message is pretty self-explanatory.  You are not explicitly inserting into the column `d_f` and it also has no default value, so your database doesn't know how to proceed.  Either pass in a value in your `INSERT` or assign a default at the database level (better).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in you comment, `d_f` is a column in your table.

So I think, it is being defined as Not-Nullable in your table without a default value.

**Two possible solutions** :

1. If you want to keep that field as optional while doing an insert, make it nullable in your table
2. If you want it to be not null, give it a default value (either at code or database level) .

Answer (score 4):

It's exactly what the error says. you have a field called d_f in your table but you are not inserting anything into that column with this statement produced by your code.

```
INSERT INTO cmd(a, b, c) VALUES(233,4.3,0.040)
```

Since a default value has not been specied for that column the database doesn't know what to do and returns this error.

You have two options, alter your table to create a default value or pass in some default value as follows

```
INSERT INTO cmd(a, b, c, d_f) VALUES(233,4.3,0.040,'some default')
```

A third option is to modify the table to allow nulls as suggested by @chris569 and as @tim-biegeleisen points out, it is indeed better to do this at the database level rather than in your java code.

Comment: Or allow NULL for d_f

Comment: I vote for handling this at the database level if at all possible, so that you don't have to reproduce logic in multiple places in your code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like '**d_f**' is a column in your table, which is not nullable,

**There are three possible ways to resolve this issue**

1. Make that column nullable
2. Provide some default value to that column e.g current timestamp
3. Put some value for that column while inserting records

Answer (score 0):

Your query might have a problem. Why don't u try by creating a prepared statement instead as below.

```
    `String a = "somevalue";
String b = "somevalue";

String c = "somevalue";

String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO cmd"
                    + "(a, b, c) " + "VALUES"
                    + "(?, ?, ?)";
                System.out.println("insertTableSQL - " + insertTableSQL);    
 Statement.executeUpdate(insertTableSQL,a,b,c); `
```

Comment: i am not giving here a single value for a , b and c here i am trying to print a array string so it is not possible to write a single value like this        + "(a, b, c) " + "VALUES"
                    + "(?, ?, ?)";